# Custom Daemons, insserv: Service crystald has to be enabled to start service Crystal Send

Tags: linux, init

I have 2 custom daemons and one (crystal_send) relies on the other (crystald) however I keep getting these error whenever I try the command `sudo update-rc.d crystal_send defaults` to update the rcX files.

`update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing

insserv: Service crystald has to be enabled to start service Crystal Send

insserv: exiting now!

update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header`

However I do enable the daemon crystald with this command.
`sudo update-rc.d crystald enable`

My headers on my /etc/init.d/ files are.

```
## /etc/init.d/crystald
##
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          Crystal Capture
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog mysql
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Crystal Capturing tool
### END INIT INFO

## /etc/init.d/crystal_send
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          Crystal
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog crystald
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Crystal Send tool
### END INIT INFO
```